# vb.net textbox not displaing value

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

In my frmMain class I have a textbox(txtCustomer) which populates from a database. I want to pass this value to another textbox in frmDepartment(txtDeptCustomer).

I am failing to see the logic of why the code I am using is not displaying a value in txtDeptCustomer. I can query the database ok with the variable, so the string is being passed through, but just not displaying in txtDeptCustomer. I would be grateful if someone could point out my error. Thanks

frmDepartment

```
Dim customer As Object = frmMain.txtCustomer.Text
```

This is passing correct value to db.

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM Departments where Customer = '" & CType(customer, String) & "'"
```

textbox txtDeptCustomer <--- NOT DISPLAYING VALUE

```
Private Sub txtDeptCustomer_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtDeptCustomer.TextChanged
        txtDeptCustomer.Text = CType(customer, String)
    End Sub
```

Comment: Where is declared the customer variable? And why do you use an object when every use of this variable requires a string?

Comment: Is there any error shown? Is `txtDeptCustomer` `public`? Do you call the `frrmDepartment` from `frmMain`?

Comment: @Edper I put in try catch and no error show. Thanks

Comment: @Steve I could have just done Dim customer As string = frmMain.txtCustomer.Text and just called customer. I thought I had declared it in frmDepartment in my code above. Thanks

Comment: I hope you could show us more code, like when you call `frmDepartment` from `frmMain`. Because it could be a just simple matter of passing values between `Forms`.

Comment: @Edper I call from frmMain by button_click frmDepartment.show(). I am passing values between forms.

Comment: I wish to know if that `customer` is a declared at the global class level or it is declare as local variable inside a method.

Comment: @Steve I only have it declared like thus: Public Class frmDepartment
    Dim customer As Object = frmMain.txtCustomer.Text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must declare then as `public` your `customer` variable in `frmDepartment`, like:

```
 Public customer as String
```

And in the `button click` from your `frmMain` you pass the value like:

```
frmDepartment.customer = txtCustomer.Text
frmDepartment.Show()
```

And then in Loading your `frmDepartment` you have now the option of assigning `customer` to `txtDeptCustomer` like:

```
Private Sub frmDepartment_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    txtDepartment.Text = customer
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Public Customer as String = Nothing

    Private Sub btnDO_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDoWork.Click
        Customer = Database Call
        Dim frmDepartmentInstance as new frmDepartment
        frmDepartment.ShowDialog(Me)
    End Sub
```

Then in the Load event of frmDepartment you can say

```
txtDeptCustomer.Text = frmMain.Customer
```

Proof of concept: New Project. Two forms | Form 1 has a button and a textbox | Form2 just has textbox

```
Public Class Form1
    Public Test As String = Nothing
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Test = TextBox1.Text
        Dim frm2 As New Form2
        frm2.ShowDialog(Me)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Form2
Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    TextBox1.Text = Form1.Test
End Sub
End Class
```